# QGIS 2.2.0-Valmiera 64bit on windows 8.1 displays error while creating ROI in SAC plugin

Tags: qgis, python, open-source-gis, classification

I don't know what happened while creating ROI during Classification using Semi automatic Classification Plugin 3.1.0 "Rome" installed on hp Pavillion i7 with windows 8.1
When i started to generate ROI on virtual raster.

> It appears that SciPy is not correctly installed. Please, see this page for information about SciPy installation  http://semiautomaticclassificationmanual.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation_win64.html#scipy-installation

To cope with the above mentioned error, I downloaded the updated scipy scipy-0.14.0.win-amd64-py3.4 from the mentioned website and place the files in the below mentioned path.
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages
But still it failed and generate the same message. The second attempt to cope with the problem is that i have removed the QGIS and install it again without giving space in name of path directory but still the problem is there.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by installing the QGIS 2.4 Chugiak 64bit for windows.